# centos 7.5 attempting to create vm using kickstart and get error cannot find /etc./iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi file

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, kvm, iscsi

I'm using the command:

```
sudo virt-install --name tester1.example.com --ram 2048 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/tester1.example.com.qcow2,format=qcow2,size=12 --location=ftp://192.168.1.88/pub/inst --nographics --initrd-inject=/home/ralph/newks.cfg --extra-args="ks=file:/newks.cfg console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"
```

with a kickstarter file that contains:

```
#versioon=DEVEL
# System authorization information
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
# Use network installation
url --url="ftp://192.168.1.88/pub/inst"
# Use graphical install
graphical
# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable
ignoredisk --only-use=vda
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8

# Network information
#network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --ipv6=auto --activate
#network  --hostname=localhost.localdomain
network --device=eth0 --bootproto=static --ip=192.168.122.100 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --gateway=192.168.122.1 --nameserver=192.168.122.1 --hostname=tester1.example.com

# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $6$nBbXk9XoFUh8swe9$l4fmEaa58TFaj814bwvfyXgztZtT4b7/PuztInGMacC6EJZMXz8MNnCnz/h.rGbKep5mcWszwTsVhsbhbk7t.1
# System services
services --enabled="chronyd"
# System timezone
timezone America/Chicago --isUtc
user --groups=wheel --name=ralph --password=$6$HHREkrcEKvhIYCCa$HAVUoPuwneIMiYKydOjPdSM0cd73uGjSG2G4.AcpjEMqsajg9SDrGAKUDClQ5OZSu95UyUciUvOXsv/ZMzgye0 --iscrypted --gecos="Ralph"
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader  --location=mbr --boot-drive=vda
autopart --type=lvm
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --none --initlabel

%packages
@^minimal
@core
chrony
kexec-tools

%end
s=DEVEL
```

and everything goes fine until the scsi disk is attached. From the install console:

```
8.506571] localhost kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

After that it times out, goes into emergency mode and I am able to peruse the error report which has the message about not being able to find the initiator file. I believe the file is supposed to be on the ramdisk, but isn't for some reason. While looking around in the ramdisk while in emergency mode I see that the file doesn't exist, but can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I took the ks=file:/newks.cfg out of extra-args and now it works fine. And if I take the initrd-inject argument and put the kickstarter file on the ftp site that works too. Just can't have both statements, which makes sense.